# How can I disable the Alt/Option key from opening Firefox in safe mode?

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, safe-mode

I'm using Quicksilver to set a global hotkey to launch Firefox: `Control+Alt+F`. The trouble is, Firefox interprets `Alt` being held down during launch as the instruction to launch in safe mode (I don't want this.)

How can I disable or change Firefox's builtin `Alt` key command for safe mode?

Comment: -safe-mode         Disables extensions and themes for this session.
    -new-window  <url> Open <url> in a new window.
    -new-tab     <url> Open <url> in a new tab.

Try forcing call of firefox.exe with -new-window or -new-tab parameter.

Comment: Such parameters would be considered in addition to the `Alt` => `-safe-mode` parameter. They wouldn't cancel it.